# In-App purchase for Android on consuming product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I use following tutorial to add in app billing for android [Google In App Billing Tutorial](https://www.gaffga.de/implementing-in-app-billing-for-android/)

and am successful in adding it.It works well for one SKU.But when i add second SKU purchase takes place but, while i consume purchase the required value doesn't adds.ie for eg i have in-app for 2 consumable products say 100 coins and 500 coins.i purchased 100 coins and consumed it works well,but after i purchase 500 coins and consume only 100 coins get consumed.i can't get  second SKU value.Can any one help me on adding multiple SKU following above tutorial link?I am trying this for weeks.Hope some one will help me.

Comment: @Hardik Thanks for the link.Btw can you find a solution with above link that i posted.

Comment: that i am telling try below demo, it may solve your problem.

Comment: @Hardik Yes.But i couldn't get those work using above code which i a still looking for solution but for time being i used this code http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

use this demo because google in app v3 demo has a some bug in `Security.java` class

https://github.com/blundell/SimpleInAppPurchaseV3